# How to make a parallax effect on a Cover Image with overlay (noJS)?

Tags: html, css, sass, jekyll

I have the [following code](https://codepen.io/MiguelPP/pen/mdQjwdg) and I'm trying to have a parallax on my cover image. I thought that all I needed to do was to have `img` have `background-attachment: fixed;` but it is not working:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 80em){
  .cover_wrapper {
    max-width: 1280px;
  }
}

.img {
  data-object-position="75% 50%";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0;
}

.cover {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 3em 0;
  clear: both;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-animation: intro 0.3s both;
  animation: intro 0.3s both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s;
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

.cover::after{
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2.441em;
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 2em 0 0.5em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.cover_wrapper {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.font{
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Roboto", "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514496959998-c01c40915c5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" data-object-position="75% 50%">
  <div class="cover">
    <div class="cover_wrapper">
      <h1 class="title font">Title</h1>
      <p class="font" style="padding-top: 140px;margin: 0px;">This is my Website</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main" role="main">
  something something
</div>
```

What can I do to have `<div id="main">` scroll over the image?

Comment: Where have you tried background attachment fixed? And what browser/OS are you on? (IOS can struggle with background-attachment fixed).

Comment: Ah, now I don't see a background image being set. What am I missing?

Comment: @AHaworth windows - mozzilla firefox

My bad I was making changes in the codepen and I didn't realise that it was automatically saving. I'll revert the changes now

Comment: @AHaworth reverted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-attachment: fixed` only works on background images. Make the `img` tag a background in the `.cover` element and add `background-attachment`.

View the mdn docs for [background-attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment)

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}



@media (min-width: 80em) {
  .cover_wrapper {
    max-width: 1280px;
  }
}

.cover {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 3em 0;
  clear: both;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-animation: intro 0.3s both;
  animation: intro 0.3s both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s;
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

.cover::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.cover {
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514496959998-c01c40915c5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80) center/cover no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2.441em;
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 2em 0 0.5em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.cover_wrapper {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.font {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Roboto", "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#main {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="cover">
    <div class="cover_wrapper">
      <h1 class="title font">Title</h1>
      <p class="font" style="padding-top: 140px;margin: 0px;">This is my Website</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main" role="main">
  something something
</div>
```

Comment: Not working on my IOS Safari.

Comment: @AHaworth yes, that is a known bug with background-attachment: fixed

Comment: Yes, ans I commented above. Perhaps a good idea to point the problem out in your answer as so very many users will be on iOS.

Comment: @brados But Then I'll lose the ability to "focus" the image in one point on mobile with `data-object-position` is there any way to work around this?